# How do i play audio file from url in android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I am developing an app with audio player.I want to play audio from url i am doing code but its plays audio from local directory i.e raw folder.I want to play song from single url at a time from play list, how to implement code in doinbackground method to play single file. What change i have to do in following code to play audio from url? Suggest me!

```
public class RelaxationLvAudioPlayerActivity1 extends Activity implements  SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private ImageButton btnPlay;
    private ImageButton btnForward;
    private ImageButton btnBackward;
    private ImageButton btnNext;
    private ImageButton btnPrevious;
    private ImageButton btnPlaylist;
    private ImageButton btnRepeat;
    private ImageButton btnShuffle;
    private SeekBar songProgressBar;
    private TextView songTitleLabel;
    private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
    private TextView songTotalDurationLabel;
    // Media Player
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    // Handler to update UI timer, progress bar etc,.
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();;
    private AudioPlayerManager songManager;
    private Utilities utils;
    private int seekForwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
    private int seekBackwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
    private int currentSongIndex = 0;
    private boolean isShuffle = false;
    private boolean isRepeat = false;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_relaxationlv_audioplayer);

        // All player buttons
        btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        //   btnForward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
        //    btnBackward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBackward);
        btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnPrevious = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
        btnPlaylist = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlaylist);
        //    btnRepeat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRepeat);
        //     btnShuffle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnShuffle);
        songProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
        songTitleLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
        songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
        songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);

        // Mediaplayer
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        songManager = new AudioPlayerManager();
        utils = new Utilities();

        // Listeners
        songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // Important

        // Getting all songs list
        songsList = songManager.getPlayList();

        // By default play first song
        playSong(0);

        /**
         * Play button click event
         * plays a song and changes button to pause image
         * pauses a song and changes button to play image
         * */
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // check for already playing
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.pause();
                        // Changing button image to play button
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                    }
                }else{
                    // Resume song
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.start();
                        // Changing button image to pause button
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // check if next song is there or not
                if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                    playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                    currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
                }else{
                    // play first song
                    playSong(0);
                    currentSongIndex = 0;
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Back button click event
         * Plays previous song by currentSongIndex - 1
         * */
        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(currentSongIndex > 0){
                    playSong(currentSongIndex - 1);
                    currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex - 1;
                }else{
                    // play last song
                    playSong(songsList.size() - 1);
                    currentSongIndex = songsList.size() - 1;
                }

            }
        });


        btnPlaylist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AudioPlayerListActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Receiving song index from playlist view
     * and play the song
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                    int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == 100){
            currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");
            // play selected song
            playSong(currentSongIndex);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Function to play a song
     * @param songIndex - index of song
     * */
    public void  playSong(int songIndex){
        // Play song
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            // Displaying Song title
            String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
            songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

            // Changing Button Image to pause image
            btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

            // set Progress bar values
            songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            songProgressBar.setMax(100);

            // Updating progress bar
            updateProgressBar();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update timer on seekbar
     * */
    public void updateProgressBar() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
    }

    /**
     * Background Runnable thread
     * */
    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
            long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

            // Displaying Total Duration time
            songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
            // Displaying time completed playing
            songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

            // Updating progress bar
            int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
            //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
            songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

            // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);

           /// mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);  //add this line
        }
    };

    /**
     *
     * */
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

    }

    /**
     * When user starts moving the progress handler
     * */
    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    }

    /**
     * When user stops moving the progress hanlder
     * */
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
        int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
        int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);

        // forward or backward to certain seconds
        mp.seekTo(currentPosition);

        // update timer progress again
        updateProgressBar();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mUpdateTimeTask != null)
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask );
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }
}



public class AudioPlayerManager{
    //    SDCard Path
    //    final String MEDIA_PATH = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
          final String MEDIA_PATH = "/sdcard/songs/";
    //      private String MEDIA_PATH =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Constructor
    public AudioPlayerManager(){

    }

    /**
     * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard
     * and store the details in ArrayList
     * */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
        //  File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                // Adding each song to SongList
                songsList.add(song);
            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }

    /**
     * Class to filter files which are having .mp3 extension
     * */
    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: adding android-mediaplayer tag

Comment: how do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
try {

  mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
  mp.setDataSource("your url");
  mp.prepare();
  mp.start();    
 } catch (Exception e) {
   // handle exception
}
```

Comment: i want to play audio with my design of media player

Comment: how do i do this?

Comment: just add this code in your custom media player where you want to play video